# Line drawn below the center of the Mouse in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, line

I am working on a simple drawing tool using JavaScript. However I have a problem with my `draw()` function. The line is always drawn slightly below the center of the mouse. May I please know what is my mistake here? I want the line to always be drawn at the center of the mouse as it moves. In my `setPosition()` function, does `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` actually maps the center of the mouse as `x` and `y` coordinates?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="clear">Clear</button> <span>Color
            <input type="color" value="#ffff00" id="penColor"></span>
    <span>Width
            <input type="range" min="1" max="20" value="10" id="penWidth"></span>
  </div>

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script>
    let penColor = document.getElementById("penColor");
    let penWidth = document.getElementById("penWidth");
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = 700;
    canvas.height = 700;

    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let clearButton = document.querySelector(".clear");

    let position = {
      x: null,
      y: null
    }

    let initialization = (e) => {
      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
      canvas.addEventListener("mouseenter", setPosition)
      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setPosition)
    }

    window.onload = initialization;

    let setPosition = (e) => {
      position.x = e.pageX;
      position.y = e.pageY;
    }

    clearButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the canvas?");

      let result = confirmation ? true : false;
      if (result) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
    })


    let draw = (e) => {
      if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(position.x, position.y);

      setPosition(e);

      context.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
      context.lineWidth = penWidth.value;
      context.strokeStyle = penColor.value;
      context.lineCap = "round";
      context.stroke();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The mouse cursor has a width/height too, you need to offset the draw line with half the cursor height when you need it to be in the center. Check [MDN: cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor),  'Usage notes' in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### MouseEvent.pageX

> The pageX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface returns the X (horizontal) coordinate (in pixels) at which the mouse was clicked, relative to the left edge of the entire document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX

so that is not the X position on the canvas, you have to substract the canvas position.

```
e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
```

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let position = { x: null, y: null }

let setPosition = (e) => {
  position.x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  position.y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}

let draw = (e) => {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(position.x, position.y);

  setPosition(e);
  context.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
  context.stroke();
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseenter", setPosition)
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setPosition)
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```